# Need to run a cron job as encrypted

Tags: soap, https, cron, cpanel

I need to setup a cron job to run a SOAP client.  The customer insists that I connect to their web service (on an https address) from an https address.  They insist that if I don't their response to me can't be encrypted.

My first question is, is that true?  I thought that as long as I'm connecting to their SOAP service over https, the response back would automatically be encrypted.

If that's true, how can I run a cron job to be as https?  My site is on a LAMP setup with cPanel access.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Either the customer has no idea how internet protocols work, or you misunderstood him.

Answer (score 0):

Your customers statement seems to be a little bit unclear in what he/she specifically means by "... connecting from an https adress" as there isn't any notion of the term "https adress" in the specs and https URLS only seem to make sense in the context of Request-URI s given in a https request.

Given this unclarity I'm only wild guessing. Nevertheless to me it seems your clients requirements might most probably **not** be connected to the http protocol but rather to establishing your TLS connection.

If your client is very sensitive in respect to the security of his system - which in fact if he intends to offer RPC requests might be a very good idea - he might not want to the whole world to be able to connect an encrypted connection to his machines and rely on any secondary authentication mechanism once the connection has been established.

As most users of the public internet don't have any certificates signed by a trusted authority this feature it isn't used out in the open wild but besides server authentication the **TLS handshake protocol** also provides a means of client authentication via **client** certificates (the relevant part being section 7 in **RFC 5246** here. see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7)

While in the absence of widely used client certificates web services usually rely on establishing an encryted connection to first to **authenticate** users by some kind of challange response test like querying for username and password your client might want to either additionally secure access to his machines by additionally requiring a valid client certificate or even - probably not the best idea - replace a second authorization like the one already mentioned above.

Nevertheless all this are nothing but some ideas that I came along with given the riddle in your question.

Most probably the best idea might be to just ask your client what he/she meant when saying "... connecting from an https adress"